# How do I get the average of consecutive positive or negative numbers into one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z99BFJws_fjrY6Z143opVntSqI5t8vG8Dkyk5-zWx68/edit?usp=sharing

A2:A16 is a column of the values
C2:C16 adds up consecutive positive and negative values in the column but I would like a formula that could get the average of those consecutive values into one cell.
H7 shows what should be the answer for the average of those 3 consecutive positive numbers.
H13 shows what should be the answer for the average of those 4 consecutive negative numbers.

Is there a formula that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will use helper column in `B2:B16`

In `B2` type this formula:

```
=IF(SIGN(A2)=SIGN(A1),B1,0)+SIGN(A2:A16)
```

and drag down up to `B16`

This will help us determine the largest count of positive and negative number.

It should look like this:

[image]

In `H7` insert this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(OFFSET(C2,MATCH(E4,B2:B16,0)-E4,0,E4,1)))
```

*This will give us the average of max consecutive positive numbers.*

In `H13` insert this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(OFFSET(C2,MATCH(-(E5),B2:B16,0)-E5,0,E5,1)))
```

*This will give us the average of max consecutive negative numbers.*

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:** You can place the helper in any column with same row and hide it, just change the formula of `H7` and `H13` that are referencing to the helper column. Also if the set max consecutive number appear more than 1, it will only calculate the first occurrence.

### References:

- [SIGN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093513?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [AVERAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615?hl=en)
- [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Amazing! Thank you so much! I have a lot of learning to do.

Comment: Actually I have a question, if you're willing. If there's two groups with the same amount of consecutive positive numbers for example, how would that look? Like 3 positive numbers in a row, then two negative numbers, then three positive numbers in a row. How would the formula change if you're trying to average the two groups?